# How to model a changing constraint in linear programming?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

I have $N$ constraints like the following:

$$B_n \geq x_nA_n,\forall n\in\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$$

where $x_n$ is a binary variable and $A_n$ and $B_n$ are part of the input.

If I have $B=(B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_N)$, I am done. But the problem is that $B_n$ changes depending on the solution $x_n$. Explicitly,

$$B_{n+1}=B_n-x_nC_n.$$

So if $x_n=0$, then $B_{n+1}=B_n$ but if $x_{n}=1$, then $B_{n+1}=B_n-C_n$. Here I know, $A=(A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_N)$ and $C=(C_1,C_2,\ldots,C_N)$ but don't know $B=(B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_N)$.

Is there any way to model these constraints in linear programming?

Comment: Why don't you simply substitute the expression for $B_n$, $n \geq 2$, in the original inequality as $B_n = B_1 - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i C_i$?

Comment: But I will get only one constraint for $B_N$, like this: $B_N=B_1-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}x_nC_n$. I won't get it for all $n$.

Comment: To clarify you do know $B_1$? Because that is the only one inaccessible by the changing rule.

Comment: You can substitute the above expression for $B_n$ in the inequality constraints to get the constraints $B_1 \geq x_1 A_1$, $B_1 - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i C_i \geq x_n A_n$, $n \in \{2,\cdots,N\}$.

Comment: Yes, I know $B_1$

Comment: Just use $B_{n+1}=B_n−x_n C_n$ and $B_n≥x_n A_n$ as given. These are all linear so can be used immediately.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen But the actual value of $B_n$ is not given. We know $B_1$ but $B_2$ depends on whether $x_1=1$ or $0$, etc.

Comment: That is no problem. $B_n$ should be a decision variable.